# User Preferences table with Microsoft Identity 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am trying to extend and store user preferences using Microsoft Identity 2 of a Survey MVC Web Application into the Database.

For now, I just want to store the user's dashboard question type view (1 to 5 stars, or 0 to 10 NPS system).

I have created a table AspNetUserPreferences with the following properties:

```
Id (int)
UserId (nvarchar(128))
DashboardQuestionType (int)
```

And the model:

```
[Table("AspNetUserPreferences")]
public class UserPreference
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public QuestionType DashboardQuestionType { get; set; }
}

public enum QuestionType
{
    [Display(Name = "Enum_Type_Numeric_1_to_5_Display", ResourceType = typeof(ResQuestion))]
    Numeric1to5 = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Enum_Type_Numeric_0_to_10_Display", ResourceType = typeof(ResQuestion))]
    Numeric0to10 = 2,
    [Display(Name = "Enum_Type_Text_Display", ResourceType = typeof(ResQuestion))]
    Text = 3,
    [Display(Name = "Enum_Type_Yes_No_Display", ResourceType = typeof(ResQuestion))]
    YesNo = 6
}
```

Context:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Add custom user claims here
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Company_Id", this.Company_Id.ToString()));
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("PTLocationDistrict", this.PTLocationDistrict.ToString()));
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Location_Id", this.Location_Id.ToString()));

        return userIdentity;
    }

    // Additional properties for the Application User

    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public virtual int Company_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Company_Id")]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public PTLocationDistrict PTLocationDistrict { get; set; }

    public virtual int? Location_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Location_Id")]
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("SurveyDB", throwIfV1Schema: false) { }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

When I try to run the application, it simply don't return any data from the database, and generate the error:

```
EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
```

Comment: What do your `ApplicationUser` and context classes look like?

Comment: Hi, thanks! I have edited the question with the model.

Comment: And you're not overriding the `OnModelCreating` method?

Comment: I don't have any OnModelCreating method.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Identity implementation makes use of IdentityUser, IdentityUserLogin etc which map to the tables AspNetUsers, AspNetUserLogins etc and these normally work well since handled behind the scenes with a default context. When adding a new table which is related to an Identity table (eg UserId FK nvarchar(128) the mapper does not know about this unless you tell it explicitly hence the error message (your new table is not in the default context so it cannot find primary). There is only constructor initialization in the ApplicationDbContext code so it may be sufficient to add a DbSet<>AspNetUserPreferences there and an OnModelCreating() method which defines the missing keys or reverse engineer all the tables and create a new context. You will need an AspNetUserPreference.cs class defining in the Models folder and the following additional code in the context class (suitable modified to fit your class) to hookup.

```
public virtual DBSet<AspNetUserPreference> AspNetUserPreferences { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserPreferences>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedName)
                .HasName("RoleNameIndex")
                .IsUnique()
                .HasFilter("([NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL)");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
        });
```

Comment: Hi thanks! I have solved the problem by removing the [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; } lines of code. To create the relationship between the tables I deal with the id directly.

Comment: I wouldn't normally do that since it breaks the relationships so LINQ queries may not work correctly in Entity Framework and  may not work in any case with more complex tables requiring the fluent API approach